# How to adjust ARCore light estimation in front camera

Tags: arcore

Hello I have some problems and questions about ARCore materials and lighting in front - camera

When ı paint a mesh from substancfe painter and export its textures then put them on unity material and after assigning to a mesh.Model is cool but when lighting is in the game.Model goes black.Textures does not appear.
How can i do ligthing in front camera any advices can you give? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply light Estimationfor from camera for all lights on scene and rendersetting ambient light with ARFoundation

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;

public class lightEstimationController: MonoBehaviour
{
    private ARCameraManager arCameraManager;

    private Light[] lights;

    private void Awake() 
    {
        lights = GetComponentsInChildren<Light>();
        arCameraManager = this.GetComponent<ARCameraManager>();
    }

    private void OnEnable() 
    {
        if (arCameraManager)
        arCameraManager.frameReceived += FrameUpdated;
    }

    private void OnDisable() 
    {
        if (arCameraManager)
            arCameraManager.frameReceived -= FrameUpdated;
    }

    private void FrameUpdated(ARCameraFrameEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.lightEstimation.averageBrightness.HasValue)
        {
            for(int i=0;i< lights.Length; i++)
            {
                lights[i].intensity = args.lightEstimation.averageBrightness.Value;
                
                if (args.lightEstimation.averageColorTemperature.HasValue)
                {
                    lights[i].colorTemperature = args.lightEstimation.averageColorTemperature.Value;
                }

                if (args.lightEstimation.colorCorrection.HasValue)
                {
                    lights[i].color = args.lightEstimation.colorCorrection.Value;
                }
                
            }

            float factor = args.lightEstimation.averageBrightness.Value;
            Color color = new Color(SceneConfig.SceneLightColor.r * factor, SceneConfig.SceneLightColor.g * factor, SceneConfig.SceneLightColor.b * factor);

            RenderSettings.ambientLight = color;

            //   Debug.Log(  $"Color Correction: {args.lightEstimation.colorCorrection.Value}");
            //   Debug.Log($"Color Temperature: {args.lightEstimation.averageColorTemperature.Value}");
            //   Debug.Log ( $"Brightness: {args.lightEstimation.averageBrightness.Value}");
        }



    }
}
```